# Datatables in Angular

Tags: angular, datatables

[image]

I have a problem with datatables in angular when I use this.dtTrigger.next(); then error same the image.
Besides, when I load data then not load UI pagination of Datatables, I have key F5 just worked, please support me.

Thank you so much

Comment: You're calling `Subject.next()` without supplying the next value. See [The `Subject` documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) for examples of calling `next()`.

Comment: Error is self explanatory, it expects an arguments but you did not provided one, eg. `.next(1)`